# mouse hover on animated canvas using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I'm creating this simple program, I'm just started studying JavaScript. so here's my code

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
            <title>Canvas Test</title>
            </head>
            <body>
            <section>
                <div>
                    <canvas   id="canvas" width="500" height="500">

                    </canvas>
                </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            var canvas;  
            var ctx;

            var x = 400;
            var y = 300;
            var dx = 2;
            var dy = 4;

            var a = 100;
            var b = 200;
            var da = 3;
            var db = 5;
            var WIDTH = 500;
            var HEIGHT = 500; 

            function circle(x,y,r) {
              ctx.beginPath();
              ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
              ctx.fill();
            }

            function rect(x,y,w,h) {
              ctx.beginPath();
              ctx.rect(x,y,w,h);
              ctx.closePath();
              ctx.fill();
            }


            function clear() {
              ctx.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
            }

            function init() {
              canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
              ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
              return setInterval(draw, 10);

            }

                 var c = Math.floor((Math.random()*WIDTH)+1);
                 var d = Math.floor((Math.random()*WIDTH)+1);
                 var e = Math.floor((Math.random()*WIDTH)+1);
                 var f = Math.floor((Math.random()*WIDTH)+1);
                 var g = Math.floor((Math.random()*WIDTH)+1);
                 var h = Math.floor((Math.random()*WIDTH)+1);


                 var dc = Math.floor((Math.random()*6)+1);
                 var dd = Math.floor((Math.random()*8)+1);
                 var de = Math.floor((Math.random()*7)+1);
                 var df = Math.floor((Math.random()*5)+1);
                 var dg = Math.floor((Math.random()*6)+1);
                 var dh = Math.floor((Math.random()*4)+1);

            var enTimer = null;
            function draw() {
              clearInterval(enTimer);


              ctx.fillStyle = "#FAF7F8";
              rect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
              ctx.fillStyle = "#F00";
              circle(x, y, 10);

              ctx.fillStyle = "#0772A1";
              circle(a, d, 20);

              ctx.fillStyle = "#00BB3F";
              circle(a, b, 30);

              ctx.fillStyle = "#FB0";
              circle(c, d, 15);

              ctx.fillStyle = "#E7003E";
              circle(c, y, 25);

              ctx.fillStyle = "#FF7400";
              circle(e, f, 10);

              ctx.fillStyle = "#98ED00";
              circle(g, h, 25);

              ctx.fillStyle = "#3016B0";
              circle(e, h, 30);

              ctx.fillStyle = "#8C04A8";
              circle(g, f, 15);

                ctx.fillStyle = "#009D91";
                circle(x, f, 30);

              if (x + dx > WIDTH || x + dx < 0)
                dx = -dx;
              if (y + dy > HEIGHT || y + dy < 0)
                dy = -dy;

            if (a + da > WIDTH || a + da < 0)
                da = -da;
              if (b + db > HEIGHT || b + db < 0)
                db = -db;

                if (c + dc > WIDTH || c + dc < 0)
                dc = -dc;
              if (d + dd > HEIGHT || d + dd < 0)
                dd = -dd;

                    if (e + de > WIDTH || e + de < 0)
                de = -de;
              if (f + df > HEIGHT || f + df < 0)
                df = -df;

                    if (g + dg > WIDTH || g + dg < 0)
                dg = -dg;
              if (h + db > HEIGHT || h + db < 0)
                dh = -dh;
            /*
                if(ctx.onmouseover = 1){
                      x += 0;
              y += 0;
              a += 0;
              b += 0;

              c += 0;
              d += 0;

                e += 0;
              f += 0;

                g += 0;
              h += 0;
                }
                else if(ctx.onmouseout = 0){*/
              x += dx;
              y += dy;
              a += da;
              b += db;

              c += dc;
              d += dd;

                e += de;
              f += df;

                g += dg;
              h += dh;
             //}
                     var interval = getRand(200000, 000);
                    enTimer = setInterval(addEnemy, interval);
            }

            init();
            function pause() {
              clearInterval(enTimer);


              ctx.fillStyle = "#FAF7F8";
              rect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
              ctx.fillStyle = "#F00";
              circle(x, y, 10);

              ctx.fillStyle = "#0772A1";
              circle(a, d, 20);

              ctx.fillStyle = "#00BB3F";
              circle(a, b, 30);

              ctx.fillStyle = "#FB0";
              circle(c, d, 15);

              ctx.fillStyle = "#E7003E";
              circle(c, y, 25);

              ctx.fillStyle = "#FF7400";
              circle(e, f, 10);

              ctx.fillStyle = "#98ED00";
              circle(g, h, 25);

              ctx.fillStyle = "#3016B0";
              circle(e, h, 30);

              ctx.fillStyle = "#8C04A8";
              circle(g, f, 15);

                ctx.fillStyle = "#009D91";
                circle(x, f, 30);

              if (x + dx > WIDTH || x + dx < 0)
                dx = -dx;
              if (y + dy > HEIGHT || y + dy < 0)
                dy = -dy;

            if (a + da > WIDTH || a + da < 0)
                da = -da;
              if (b + db > HEIGHT || b + db < 0)
                db = -db;

                if (c + dc > WIDTH || c + dc < 0)
                dc = -dc;
              if (d + dd > HEIGHT || d + dd < 0)
                dd = -dd;

                    if (e + de > WIDTH || e + de < 0)
                de = -de;
              if (f + df > HEIGHT || f + df < 0)
                df = -df;

                    if (g + dg > WIDTH || g + dg < 0)
                dg = -dg;
              if (h + db > HEIGHT || h + db < 0)
                dh = -dh;


                      x += 0;
              y += 0;
              a += 0;
              b += 0;

              c += 0;
              d += 0;

                e += 0;
              f += 0;

                g += 0;
              h += 0;
                     var interval = getRand(200000, 000);
                    enTimer = setInterval(addEnemy, interval);
            }

            </script>

            </section>
            </body>
            </html>
```

what I want is , when i hover the canvas the animation will stop, and when i hover out the animation will play, i tried putting onmouseover and onmouseout but it doesn't work

P.S use javascript only, no libraries like jquery

Comment: can you create a [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net) of this?

Comment: here http://jsfiddle.net/lightblue/ADTd9/

Answer (score 1):

You almost have it...

Be sure your timer in init() is public:

```
function init() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  enTimer=setInterval(draw, 10);

}
```

Add some event listeners that kill the timer on mouseover and create a new timer on mouseout:

```
// listen for mouseover on the canvas 

canvas.addEventListener("mouseover",doMouseOver,false);

// listen for mouseout from the canvas

canvas.addEventListener("mouseout",doMouseOut,false);


// on mouseover, clear the timer

function doMouseOver(){
    clearInterval(enTimer);
}


// on mouseout, start another timer

function doMouseOut(){
    var interval = getRand(200000, 000);   // or make interval public to make it reusable
    enTimer = setInterval(addEnemy, interval);
}
```